# Static int wont trigger remove frame or change panel

Tags: java

I am creating a program using NetBeans 11.2 that has an animation in it. While creating it after the animation when the static variable (CurrentFrame is equal to 176) I want the Frame to remove the Jpanel so I can add pictures of cars to my program and move the pictures. so i made an if statement so when `Currentframe == 176` it will remove said panel but it wont work no matter what i do. I did System.out.print to see if it even counted up to 176 and it did. So what's the problem any tips?
package Frametest;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public final Timer animate;
public static Boolean z = false;
public final ImageIcon ImageArray[];
public static int delay = 50, FrameCount = 177, Currentframe = 0;

public Main() {

    ImageArray = new ImageIcon[FrameCount];

    //Array used to store 200 Frames 
    for (int i = 1; i < ImageArray.length; i++) {

        ImageArray[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Cartest (" + i + ").jpg"));

        //i++ causes the Array to constantly pull up an image that i have named 
        //from numbers 1-200
    }

    animate = new Timer(delay, this);
    animate.start();
    //Setting a delay using a timer

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println(Currentframe);
    Currentframe++;

    ImageArray[Currentframe].paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    //each time this method is called the image is going to differentiate 

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    do {
        repaint();
    } while (Currentframe >= ImageArray.length);

    //clears the graphics and images and recalls the method
}

static class Action implements ActionListener {

    

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("hello");
       
        Main s = new Main();
        f.add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1280, 760);
        f.setVisible(true);

        if (Currentframe == 176) {
            f.getContentPane().removeAll();
            f.setVisible(false);
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Title Page
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Button Example");
    JButton b = new JButton("Click Here");

    b.setBounds(50, 100, 95, 30);

    f.add(b);
    b.addActionListener(new Action());
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);   

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues to address.

The first being the location of the code that *should* remove the `JPanel` from the `JFrame`:

```
if (Currentframe == 176) {
    f.getContentPane().removeAll();
    f.setVisible(false);
}
```

This condition is checked only once when you add the `ActionListener` to the `JButton`. So remove this code. This logic has to be moved to the `actionPerformed` method in class `Main`.

The second problem is your `Timer`. It won't stop running automatically by only removing the `JPanel`. You'll have to stop it explicitly (and optionally restart it when required).

**A general note**: don't start variable names with an uppercase letter. This is considered bad practice.

The solution:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    do {
        repaint();
    } while (Currentframe >= ImageArray.length);

    if (Currentframe == 176) {
        animate.stop();
        this.getRootPane().removeAll();
        //optional, without repainting the image which was painted last will remain visible
        //JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        //topFrame.repaint();
    }
}
```